# VB 2010: How to index textbox (making it like slots)?

Tags: vb.net, string, textbox

If the title isn't clear; I want to be able to select any character from textbox without making some complex loops-dependent code (I can do that one). For example, let's consider this text is entered in a textbox:

> hello user!

I want some syntax when I tell to get me the index 1's value, it gives me "h", for index 5 = "o"... etc

So, anyone knows what's the right syntax, please help!

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, em3ricasforsale had given me the very right answer... Thank you all :-D... My greeting to all of you.

Comment: His code is completely unnessacary as I said below. strings are directly indexable, just say mystring(myindex) and you get the char. Using that is exactly the same as mystring.ToArray()(myIndex), which is exactly the same as mystring(myindex)!

Comment: 'vb' tag is being phased out as ambiguous, and the index tags have other, more specific meanings related to databases. They don't belong with your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string` can be directly indexed without any special code.

```
//from metadata
public sealed class String : IComparable, ICloneable, IConvertible, IComparable<string>, IEnumerable<char>, IEnumerable, IEquatable<string>
{
    ....
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the character at a specified character position in the current System.String
    //     object.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   index:
    //     A character position in the current string.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     A Unicode character.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.IndexOutOfRangeException:
    //     index is greater than or equal to the length of this object or less than
    //     zero.
    public char this[int index] { get; }
    ....
}


dim str = "hello";

dim hchar = str(0);
dim echar = str(1);
dim lchar = str(2);
ect
```

Comment: Thank you asawyer, I wish you the best with your programming life.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim x As String = "Hello"

Console.Write(x.IndexOf("e")) 'Would return the position
Console.Write(x(x.IndexOf("e"))) 'Would return the character based upon the position
Console.Write(x(1)) 'Returns the character based at position 1 of the string
```

You can remove the Console.Write if you are using a WinForm.

```
TextBox1.Text = x(x.IndexOf("e"))
```

Comment: Thank you... I wish you the best!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
Dim orig = "hello user!"
Dim res = Enumerable.Range(0,orig.Length).[Select](Function(i) orig.Substring(i,1))
```

So then you can do:

```
Dim x = res(0)  'x = "h"
```

Comment: I have to say, I find this solution very strange.

Comment: Thank you em3ricasforsale,
It does the job greatly... but, I didn't understand what does it mean!! :-P... never mind, I'll study it carefully, and in Allah's will, I'll understand it....
Thank you from my heart's deeps...